# I want to block certain directories in my hosting

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering if someone knows how to block certain directories such as "http://www.example.com/images, css, includes" etc. Because when I type my web address with a sub directory, it shows what's inside those sub-directories such as my css files, images etc. I have read about a few articles about this but failed to understand as I have very poor knowledge in computer.

Comment: But you still want to allow: `http://www.example.com/images/abc.png1`?

Comment: Basically you are looking for [Options -Indexes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#options).

Comment: I have no idea about the whole thing. All I want is to block these 3 directories 
1. CSS
2.Images
3.Includes

Comment: What do you mean by block? If requests come from a valid css file from your webpage, do you want to block that also?

Comment: Well, if I type this path "www.example.com/css or images" it directly goes to the that particular directory (css or images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this one rule in root .htaccess to block those directories listings:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(css|images|includes|js)/?$ - [NC,F]
```